# How can I save the random numbers and count how many times they appeared throughout the game?

Tags: c, random, save

So I'm trying to do lottery game and I'm supposed to write down top 3 numbers that appeared throughout the game in the Statistics. But I'm not sure how to save or count how many times a number appeared.

```
int i,s,ans,ans1;
 MENU: ;
srand(time(0));
printf("[1]-Play The Game\n[2]-Statistics\n");
scanf(" %d",&ans1);

if(ans1==1){

PLAY: ;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
      s=1+rand()%9;
      printf("%d.number=%d \n",i,s); }

 QUESTION: ;
  printf("\nWant to roll again? \n [1]-Yes\n[2]-No\nAnswer:");
  scanf("%d",&ans);
      if(ans==1)
        goto PLAY;
      else if (ans==2)
        goto MENU;
      else
        goto QUESTION;
  }

   else if (ans1==2){
    printf("\n\t Welcome to Statitistics");

    for(int a=0;a<3;a++){
        printf("\n%d",s);
    }

   }
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: There are cases when using `goto` is okay. Instead of loops is *not* one of those cases.

Comment: Also you should call `srand` only *once*.

Comment: This code is just prototype. All I want to know how to keep track on how many numbers appeared how many times. But thanks for the response

Comment: You can get nine different values, from `1` to `9`. How about an array to store the count of them?

Comment: As @user3121023 wrote, create an array `int counts[]` where `counts[i]` will contain the number of occurrences for the `i`-th number. By writing `static int counts[9] = {0};` you will allocate an array of static duration for storing 9 numbers (indices 0 to 8), initialized to zero initially. You will then increment the value for each random number, i.e. `++counts[s - 1];`. Note that `counts[9]` is outside the bounds of the array, and your `s` contains values 1 to 9. So one alternative is also to initialize `counts` to store 10 numbers, for simplicity, and then use `++counts[s];`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a 2D Array consists of possible number and its cnt.(Possible number 1-9, cnt = 0 for each)
On each random number generation. Increment count of that number.

Create a function to find max 3 from an array.
On show statistics logic call it by passing previously created 2D array.
It will find the top 3 numbers.

Comment: Consider add some code example, it will be much more cleaner

Comment: Given small range of possible numbers, simpler to use 1D array, as per comments to OP

Answer (score 0):

```
#define SIZE 10
int f[SIZE]; // increment f[x] each time x appears in the lottery
void find3max_count(int *a, int *b, int *c){
    *a = *b = *c = 0;
    int fa = -1, fb = -1, fc = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        if(f[i] > fa){
            *c = *b; fc = fb;
            *b = *a; fb = fa;
            *a = i; fa = f[i];
        }else if(f[i] > fb){
            *c = *b; fc = fb;
            *b = i; fb = f[i];
        }else if(f[i] > fc){
            *c = i; fc = f[i];
        }
    }
}
```

This function should be called like this:

```
int a, b, c;
find3max_count(&a, &b, &c);
```

And after it was executed, a, b and c will have the numbers that appeared the most during the lottery.

If you had way more numbers to count and look for, sorting may be more useful.

```
typedef struct {
    int x, freq;
} freq_elem;
freq_elem f[SIZE];
```

Initialize with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    f[i].x = i;
    f[i].freq = 0;
}
```

Each time x appears in the lottery, do:

```
f[x].freq++;
```

Function that compares 2 freq_elem:

```
int cmp(const void* a, const void* b){
    return ((freq_elem*)b)->freq - ((freq_elem*)a)->freq; // order by freq in decreasing order
}
```

The function:

```
void find_k_maxCount(freq_elem v[], int k){
    qsort(f, SIZE, sizeof(freq_elem), cmp);
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        v[i] = f[i];
}
```

After calling this function, the array `v` will have the `k` elements that appeared the most during the lottery.